# scrapy crawl MySpider -o items.json outputs one json object per line

Tags: python, json, scrapy, web-crawler

This is what I get (not a valid json object):

```
{"id": 1, "name": John}
{"id": 2, "name": Tom}
```

This is what I would like to get (valid json object):

```
[{"id": 1, "name": John},
{"id": 2, "name": Tom}]
```

I would like to be able to do it directly from with scrapy's command line tool (crawl).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [JsonItemExporter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.contrib.exporter.JsonItemExporter) and not the [JsonLinesItemExporter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.contrib.exporter.JsonItemExporter). However be aware that the JsonLines exporter is much better for large output files, as you can parse the file as a stream.